# How to set requirements like "at most n times" by using z3py?

Tags: python, z3, z3py

I am new to python and new to z3.I am trying to solve some SMT problems by z3py.
Now I need to set a restriction: array1(1,8) has at least 5 zeros. However I meet some bugs.

`al1,al2,al3,al4,al5,al6,al7,al8=Ints('al1 al2 al3 al4 al5 al6 al7 al8')`

this is what I declared and when I want to use`al1=If(be1*wi1,1,0)`, there will be an error saying that `Z3Exception: Value cannot be converted into a Z3 Boolean value`
or`Z3Exception: Symbolic expressions cannot be cast to concrete Boolean values`

**I want to know how to count how many zeros among these elements?** and I'm not sure if this declaration can be changed...I just copied this part from example..

Comment: Please post a minimal but complete example that allows reproducing your problems. Regarding your goal (at most n times): you could use existentials (there do not exist five distinct indices at which the array has a particular value); if the array is of statically known length, existentials can be replaced by disjunctions; depending on the values in the array, a solution with sums/products might be an option.

Answer (score 0):

It's always best to post your full code so people can see and comment what exactly you tried.

In either case, to express such at-least/at-most sorts of constraints, you should use the so-called "pseudo-boolean" constraints. For instance, to say that at least 5 of these elements are 0, you can say:

```py
from z3 import *

al1,al2,al3,al4,al5,al6,al7,al8 = Ints('al1 al2 al3 al4 al5 al6 al7 al8')

s = Solver()

s.add(AtLeast(al1 == 0, al2 == 0, al3 == 0, al4 == 0, al5 == 0, al6 == 0, al7 == 0, al8 == 0, 5))

print(s.check())
print(s.model())
```

When I run this, I get:

```
sat
[al8 = 1,
 al7 = 1,
 al6 = 1,
 al5 = 0,
 al4 = 0,
 al3 = 0,
 al2 = 0,
 al1 = 0]
```

As you see 5 of the variables are 0. (Obviously this isn't the only possible model, but one that z3 found for you. You can add other constraints obviously.)

For details on pseudo-boolean constraints see here: https://z3prover.github.io/api/html/namespacez3py.html#a8575bdeb9d1b8feac119aa162b5acfa6

The functions you want to look into are called: `AtMost`, `AtLeast`, `PbLe`, `PbGe`, and `PbEq`.